# Problem accessing WFS 1.1.0 with Mapinfo

Tags: mapinfo, wfs

I am new to all kinds of GIS software. Due to my project I need to open WFS site which needs a WFS standard 1.1.0. I tried to do it with MapInfo Professional 11.5, but it wont open it. I found a solution from the internet which told me to put ?request=getCapabilities&version=1.1.0 in the end of my WFS URL, but it gives me an error " Unable to get capabilities from the server " Do I have to download any add-ons to MapInfo 11.5? Or can anybody suggest me some other programs to get this link to work?

Comment: Can you share the link? Can you determine which server is used (the best way to do so is often to open the link and to add a bogus request).

Comment: I checked it out meanwhile - that server really supports only 1.1.0

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is still little bit ambiguos. Did I understood correctly, that WFS service supports only 1.1.0, but MapInfo supports only 1.0.0?

There is service=WFS missing in your request string. Open those two URL-s in browser, what do you get?

http://url.to.your.serice?request=getCapabilities&version=1.1.0&service=WFS
http://url.to.your.serice?request=getCapabilities&version=1.0.0&service=WFS

For testing (if you are stuck with MapInfo), you can download Quantum GIS (http://www.qgis.org/), it supports WFS.

Comment: I tried these two URL´s (with Mapinfo 11.5) - with the first URL I got the same error " Unable to get capabilities from the WFS server", with the other one (1.0.0) it was OK. But the problem is that the server i need to open needs WFS standard 1.1.0, it would not open with 1.0.0. The company that gave me the server link told that I need to download some kind of add-ons to Mapinfo 11.5, but they wont tell me what kind of add-ons. Any ideas ?

Comment: 1) Ask again from company, that gave WFS url 2) Ask from your MapInfo retailer

Comment: In addition to my previous comment: As said in http://critchlowli.wordpress.com/tag/mapinfo-professional/ support for 1.1.0 will be in upcoming 11.5.2. Download section of Mapinfos home page doesn't offer even update to 11.5.1. So asking from retailer may be your best shot.

Comment: Now I tried with QuantumGIS. I managed to connect with server but when I am trying to apply the coordinates to the map, QuantumGIS crashes :/

Comment: MapInfo Professional doesn't support WFS 1.1.0 yet. It will be supported when we release 11.5.2 within the next month or so.